# How to encode time strptime format

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, decode

I have a python code for **`time.strptime`** and the format is like this:

```
start_date = time.strptime('2019-03-25', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

But now if my users try to input the time that is not according to the format it will give an error.

Let's say if users try to input the date format like this:

```
start_date = time.strptime('25-03-2019', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

That will give an error message

```
ValueError: time data '25-03-2019' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

So, how to encode the string to automatically give to the format the server provide..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there will always be cases that are ambiguous, you can use `dateutil` ([python-dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) on pypi) to parse dates from most standard formats:

```
>>> import dateutil
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('25-03-2019')
datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 25, 0, 0)
#                 ^     ^   ^
#              year, month, day
```